# Azure Pipelines Retention Policy support

Tags: azure-pipelines

What is going on? It's been a year since Microsoft has promised to support Retention Policy in Azure Pipelines

Azure DevOps Server On-Premesis
Version 17.143.28621.4

I looked at the release notes, you still don't have it in the latest stable version.

YAML Code not available because feature does not exist

We need a way to specify with YAML code to set retention policies for a the build pipeline

Comment: Hey Jason, I would get in touch with Microsoft Azure Pipelines support about this issue. Stack Overflow would not be the recommended platform to voice these concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Donot know if i understand you correctly? Retention Policies should be able to set under the **Pipelines setting** under **project settings** and **organization settings**. check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/retention?view=azure-devops) for Official documents

[image]

If you want to submit a user voice. You can go to this [site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to report a problem or suggest a feature.